# I am trying to set data in state everytime on first index for react in array of object

Tags: reactjs, api, setstate, react-state

```
state = {
    resposne: [{ id: null, sentMessage: "", receviedMessage: "" }],
  };
```

this is my state object
I am fetching data from an API:

```
/*CONSIDER ABOVE API CALL IS WORKING AS I AM RECEIVING DATA ALREADY*/
.then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
if (data) {
this.setState(
            this.state.response.push({
              id: data.id,
              receivedMessage: data.choices[0].text,
              sentMessage: message,
            })
          );
          console.log(this.state);
}

}
```

I am able to receive data but don't no how to store it in state object.
my final state object should be something like this:
**API RESPONSe**

```
id:1a,
sentMessage:"hello",
receviedMessage:"Hey,How are you"
/*state should be*/
state={
response:[{id:"1a",sentMessage:"hello",receviedMessage:"Hey,How are you"}]}
```

FOR NEXT FRAME
**API RESPONSe**

```
id:1b,
sentMessage:"new message",
receviedMessage:"this is new message"
/*state should be*/
state={
response:[{id:1b,sentMessage:"new message",receviedMessage:"this is new message"},{id:"1a",sentMessage:"hello",receviedMessage:"Hey,How are you"}]}
```

**AS YOU CAN SEE THIS LAST RESPONSE IS SET TO FIRST INDEX(I AM USING CLASS BASED COMPONENTS IN REACT NO HOOKS)**

***CONSOLE OUTPUT***
[0:{id:NULL,sentMessage:"",receivedMessage:""},1:{id:1b,sentMessage:"new message",receviedMessage:"this is new message"},{id:"1a",sentMessage:"hello",receviedMessage:"Hey,How are you"},response:[...]]
***HERE IS OUTPUT OF CONSOLE: with below soltion***

```
this.setState({
            response: [
              ...this.state.resposne,
              {
                id: data.id,
                receivedMessage: data.choices[0].text,
                sentMessage: message,
              },
            ],
          });
```

[image]

Comment: What is inside state you receive in `console.log(this.state)`

Comment: I receive data in array of object formate but it's not as per my expectation. I have added it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you call the setState has not the required format (the piece of the state that is going to update)

Either of the following ways will work

##### Directly set the piece of the state object

```
this.setState({
  response: [
    ...this.state.response,
    {
      id: data.id,
      receivedMessage: data.choices[0].text,
      sentMessage: message
    }
  ]
});
```

##### Using the callback function of setState method

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  response: [
    ...prevState.response,
    {
      id: data.id,
      receivedMessage: data.choices[0].text,
      sentMessage: message
    }
  ]
}));
```

Comment: callback function giving error of not iterable and first approach is still not as per my expectation. I am adding a screenshot of the output with the first approach.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer mispelled `response` as  `resposne`. Not it is fixed. can you please check again? refresh your app and check the changes

Comment: App.js:71 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.response is not iterable
    at App.js:71:1 Tihis error is coming.

Comment: can you see that same typo is in the initial state as `resposne`. It should work after fixing it.

Comment: Yes I changed response to both places :(

Comment: Thank you it worked I forget to change spell at state